# Java better way to code this simple parameter intake?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

"Employee identification number (a string) in the format XXX-L, where each X is a digit within the range 0-9 and the L is a letter within the range ‘A’-‘M’ (both lowercase and uppercase letters are acceptable)"

The above is a field which will be an argument for the constructor. Right now, I'm planning on making sure the the first 3 letters of the string is a number between 0-9, and then make sure there is a dash in the index of 4, and then make sure there is a letter between A-M in the 5th index, all using if else statements. Is there a better way of doing this, like if the entering of the parameter didn't have to be so exact, and the programs able to fix it by itself? Thank you.

I coded it and tried regex expression tools:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Employee {

private String eName;
private String IDNumber;

public Employee(String name, String number) {
    String regex = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][\\-][a-mA-M]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);
    this.eName = name;
    if(matcher.matches()) {
    this.IDNumber = number;
    } else{
        this.IDNumber = "999-M";
    }

}

public String getNumber() {
    System.out.println(IDNumber);
    return IDNumber;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e = new Employee("John", "123-f");
    e.getNumber();
    Employee c = new Employee("Jane","25z");
    c.getNumber();
}

}
```

I haven't thoroughly tested it, but it works, but looking at other people's regex expression, mine seems to be very newbish. I was wondering if someone can help me construct a shorter or better regex expression.

Comment: don't simply ask for code, show your effort

Comment: You can only ask if there is a better way of doing something if you've actually done something first... I don't see any code so I assume you haven't done anything. In which case, try something first.

Comment: If you know `regex` you can do the verification without multiple `if` statements.

Comment: @PM77-1 can you see if its usable? Thank you.

Comment: @JoshM Can you take a look at it now?

Comment: `"^[0-9]{3}-[a-mA-M]$"` or `"^\\d{3}-[a-mA-M]$"`

Comment: @PM77-1 If you were to answer it, I'd be able to choose yours as an accepted answer. I don't know how to do it otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\\d{3}-[a-mA-M]$
```

This should be an improvement I think.

1. `^` means the start of the text
2. `\d` means any digit (backslash itself needs to be escaped)
3. `{3}` means previous match 3 times
4. the hyphen is a `literal`, as long as it isn't in square brackets
5. `[a-mA-M]` means any upper or lower case letter as you knew
6. `$` means the end of the text

I used this site to test it out on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: it says invalid escape sequence when I put it in eclipse, but thanks anyway

Comment: That'll be something specific to java, you can just escape it like you had previously done. But it doesn't need to be in square brackets as that's for a range of characters that could match.